# use one useRef for multiple elements

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I Have a react component that is holding

```
const inputSchemaVersionRef =useRef<HTMLInputElement>();
```

The components has multiple text Fields and the `ref` is connected to each text Field like this:

```
inputRef={(ref) => (inputSchemaVersionRef.current = ref)}
```

(it is `inputRef` because MUI library). This works.

when I tried  `inputRef={inputSchemaVersionRef}`, the ref was connected to the last instance of text field.

Can someone explain why it only refers to the last text field and why I need to assign the ref to the inputSchemaVersionRef current for it to work?

Comment: Why do you want to use a ref? What do you plan to do with it? Without that info (and a [mre]), it's going to be hard to provide a useful answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`useRef` returns a ref object with a single `current` property initially set to the initial value you provided (you can check it out in [react documentation](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useRef)). That's just how it works. When you want to change the ref value, it is necessary to change the `current` property to keep the ref object reference in the memory.

As for the `inputRef` issue; It is because you have several text fields (as you said) and the ref is connected to each text field, so logically the value is replaced by each one of the text fields one by one till it gets to the last one and it stores in the ref. If you want to prevent that you can initialize `inputSchemaVersionRef`  as an empty array like this (I assume that you have two text fields):

```
const inputSchemaVersionRef =useRef<HTMLInputElement[]>([]);
```

and connect text fields to the ref like :

```
<TextField
  id="myFirstTextField"
  inputRef={ref => {
    inputSchemaVersionRef.current[0] = ref
  }}
/>
<TextField
  id="mySecondTextField"
  inputRef={ref => {
    inputSchemaVersionRef.current[1] = ref
  }}
/>
```

Or you can initialize `inputSchemaVersionRef` as a json like this:

```
const inputSchemaVersionRef = useRef<{
    myFirstTextField:HTMLInputElement | null;
    mySecondTextField:HTMLInputElement | null
  }>({myFirstTextField:null, mySecondTextField: null});
```

and then use it like below:

```
<TextField
  id="myFirstTextField"
  inputRef={ref => {
    inputSchemaVersionRef.current.myFirstTextField = ref
  }}
/>

<TextField
  id="mySecondTextField"
  inputRef={ref => {
    inputSchemaVersionRef.current.mySecondTextField = ref
  }}
/>
```

So input ref values will never get overrided.